# Dealing with direct dependency that's also a transitive dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I have a Maven project with two direct dependencies, let's call them `dep-a` and `dep-b`, that are both used heavily in the project. `dep-a` itself has a transitive dependency on `dep-b`. For compatibility reasons, I want to keep the version of `dep-b` in my project the same as the version for `dep-b` that `dep-a` declares.

Both `dep-a` and `dep-b` are third-party dependencies on Maven Central that I have no control over. `dep-b` is a project that moves pretty fast; it often releases new versions. `dep-a` is a bit slower to update. I'm looking for a practical way to manage this, while keeping versions as up-to-date as possible.

Here are some possibilities I'm considering. None of them are really satisfying to me:

- Currently, I use Dependabot in my project, which periodically checks for new versions and updates them when new ones are available. This has the disadvantage that it might update `dep-b` in my project, even when `dep-a` hasn't already done the same, which results in a version mismatch for `dep-b`.
- I could accept this as a fact of life and move on, but this doesn't actually solve the problem.
- I can ditch Dependabot and periodically update things myself. However, this is busywork that I'd rather see automated.
- I can ditch Dependabot and write an elaborate script myself, that leverages Maven's Versions plugin to check for updates. I've done this once before on another project, and it's a lot more work than I thought it would be. Also, I'd have to add some additional logic to account for the `dep-b` version.
- I can simply not declare `dep-b` in my Maven build at all, and rely on the transitive dependency. I can't think of a good reason not to do this, but it does feel dirty.

Is there a generally accepted way of dealing with this scenario that I'm overlooking?

Comment: The update of `dep-b` is "nearer" to your project than `dep-a` is? (In the meaning of distance between your own project and the dependencies like `dep-a`, `dep-b` or are those two deps direct dependencies of your project?

Comment: @khmarbaise `dep-a` and `dep-b` are both direct dependencies of my project. It's just that `dep-b` also happens to be a direct depedency of `dep-a`, which makes `dep-b` both a direct and a transitive dependency of my project. For my project it doesn't really matter if `dep-b` is a few releases old.

Answer (score 2):

> I can simply not declare dep-b in my Maven build at all, and rely on the transitive dependency. I can't think of a good reason not to do this, but it does feel dirty.

I find this as the right thing to do. `dep-a` (with version `x`) is supposed to be tested and proven that it's compatible with `dep-b` (version `y`).

If you exclude `dep-b` in the `<dependency>` block for `dep-a` and then inject it separately with a different (newer) version, then you might experience compatibility issues (especially when `dep-b` is released more frequently).

Alternatively, you can think of a way, where `dep-a` does not depend on `dep-b` and hence, they can be independently injected. If they are supposed to be released independently, they should also be independently injectable. In this case, I would think about what pieces of code from `dep-b` is used in `dep-a`, can I put it somewhere else (maybe in another library, say `dep-c`), so that `dep-a` no longer depends on `dep-b`? Things like that.

But in general, I try to avoid excluding the transitive dependencies and overwriting them with newer version, because this might lead to very complicated incompatibility issues, which are quite tough to be analyzed and resolved.

Comment: Indeed, I want to stay away from these compatibility issues. BTW, I have no control over `dep-a` or `dep-b`, they're on Maven Central and I'm not involved in them, so I can't change them. I'll update the question to make that clearer.

Comment: @jqno, in this case you can import them both, but add some documentation that in case of incompatibility issues, these two should be considered as the main suspects.

Answer (score 1):

The ultimate solution would be to convert to OSGi, so that your project could depend on `dep-b.1`, while at the same time `dep-a` could depend on `dep-b.2` without interfering with each other. However, that may not be a simple task, depending (pun intended) on the circumstances. OSGi is an all or nothing undertaking.

That said, I guess your best choice is to just depend on `dep-a` and let that decide which `dep-b` to use, and have a good night's sleep.